# Why does my clickonce application not generate an HTML file?

Tags: .net, clickonce

I have only made one other ClickOnce application in the past but it generated an HTML file when I published it.  I am working on another one now and for some reason it doesn't generate the HTML file.  The rest of the files are published fine.  I can install if I use a url directly to the setup.exe or .application file but I would like to use the default html page.  Can anyone think of any reasons why this file is not being generated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the Publish Tab, under the Options button, there is a checkbox for generating the page.

Comment: Thanks! I must have overlooked that 1000 times!